# having trouble adding a column to a temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

having below image

[image: data]

I have to create on my temp table another column named unit that will storage the value from STUNM if STTOT > 0 and STMATR <> 'FR', but if STTOT only have positive value where STMATR = 'FR'(like in above image) I will need the value from STUNM, everything grouped by STTCKT

This is the code I currently have. Now is leaving it in blank if STTOT only have positive value where STMATR = 'FR'.(Maybe this help, column rev in my temp table retuns the STTOT summary where STMATR <> 'FR')

```
select sttckt
    ,stcomp
    ,stdate
    ,stwway
    ,stvoid
    ,rwdesc
    ,stlndf
    ,cslnam
    ,cvar6
    ,cblnam
    --,unit=max(case when(sttot >0 and stmatr<>'FR') then stunm else '' end)
    ,yd=max(case when(stunm ='YD' and stmatr<>'FR') then stqty else 0 end)
    ,tn=max(case when(stunm ='TN' and stmatr<>'FR') then stqty else 0 end)
    ,ea=max(case when(stunm ='EA') then stqty else 0 end)
    ,rev=sum(case when(stmatr<>'FR' and sttot >=0) then sttot else 0 end)
    ,disp=sum(case when(stmatr<>'FR'and sttot <=-1) then sttot else 0 end)
    ,fr=sum(case when(stmatr='FR' and sttot >=0) then sttot else 0 end)
from #Test where [STTCKT] = 126601
group by sttckt,
    stcomp,
    stdate,
    stwway,
    stvoid,
    rwdesc,
    stlndf,
    cslnam,
    cblnam,
    cvar6
```

Comment: What do you want to show when `STMATR = 'FR'`? Sorry, but I was not able to understand this part of your explanation.

Comment: I want to show the STUNM that belongs to this line, in this example 'EA'